# Excel VBA - Delete Rows on certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba

If a row has the value **INACTIVE** in `column D` and **#N/A** in `column H`, I want to delete that row.

I tried to achive that with my code below, but no row actually gets deleted.

```
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim r As Integer
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
With ws3
For r = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If Cells(r, "D").Value = "INACTIVE" And Cells(r, "H").Value = "#N/A" Then
Sheet2.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: You can use `AutoFilter` to get your rows and then delete them

Comment: Your `If` is checking the value of cells in the ActiveSheet, not in Sheet2. Maybe it should be something like `If Sheet2.Cells(r, "D").Value` or `If ws3.Cells(r, "D").Value` because you are mixing things here. `ws3` is `Sheet2` or is it `Sheets("Sheet2")`? is `Sheet2=Sheets("Sheet2")` your code is totally confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues.

- You don't properly qualify your range objects.

  - You (properly) use `With ws3` but then never refer back to it
- If the `#N/A` is an actual error value, and not a text string, your macro will fail with a type mismatch error.
- If the first row of `UsedRange` is not row 1, then `rows.count.row` will not reflect the last row
- `r` should be declared as `Long`, not `Integer`.

  - `Integer` is limited to 32768 and there could be many more rows in a worksheet.
  - VBA will convert Integer to Long internally anyway.
- Also, as pointed out by @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `Sheets("Sheet2")` may not be the same as `Sheet2`.  You seem to be using them interchangeably in your code.  Set `ws3` to whichever one you really want. And examine vba HELP for `CodeName` to understand the difference.

The following modification of your code may work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
  Dim ws3 As Worksheet
  Dim r As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
With ws3
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(r, "D").Value = "INACTIVE" And .Cells(r, "H").Text = "#N/A" Then
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: while using this code, I have got the erro as "invalid outside procedure" for option explicit

Comment: @shnaky You have a typo or something other than what I have posted in your module.

Comment: @shnaky Also note that the screen shot you showed in your duplicate question does not have ANY rows that contain `INACTIVE`